# Does the ranger's Archery Fighting Style apply to the monk's Deflect Missiles feature, for a multiclassed monk/ranger?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, ranger, ranged-attack, fighting-style

I'm considering a multi-class of Monk and Ranger, and have been trying to decide which Fighting Style I'd like to pick.

Two-Weapon Fighting and Defense are useless for a Monk, as they won't be wearing armour, and using multiple weapons stops unarmed strikes.

Dueling could work, if the character uses a 1-handed monk weapon, giving a +2 to damage with it (I believe).

As for Archery, I was wondering if catching and throwing something with Deflect Missiles would get the +2 to attack. The reason I believe it would is that it counts as a **Monk Weapon** for the attack.

Does this logic look right?

Comment: To be clear: using multiple weapons does not stop unarmed strikes *per se*. You just can't use your bonus action for both in the same turn.

Comment: That's true, I had assumed I'd need to drop the second weapon but it isn't specifically a punch, could use a kick or headbutt. Good catch!

Comment: Related: [Could a Monk holding two weapons still allow for the bonus Unarmed action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114978/could-a-monk-holding-two-weapons-still-allow-for-the-bonus-unarmed-action)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No, it doesn't

The Archery fighting style says:

> You gain a +2 bonus to attack rolls you make with ranged **weapons**.

Ranged *Weapons* in this case refers to a weapon *type*, so you won't get the bonus. If this instead said, "Ranged Weapon **Attacks**", you'd get the bonus, but as is,  you're out of luck.

This is the same reason why the **Archery** style doesn't work with most* thrown weapons -- they're melee weapons with the *thrown* property!

*Darts and Nets being the exceptions, because they *are* Ranged Weapons.

Comment: Exception: darts are ranged weapons that you throw.

Comment: And Nets, for what that's worth.

Comment: do note that as a Kensei monk, you can benefit from the Archery Fighting Style, since your monk weapons can now include ranged weapons such as a longbow.

Answer (score 6):

### Unfortunately, No

The Archery fighting style requires you to make the attack with a ranged weapon:

> You gain a +2 bonus to attack rolls you make with
>   ranged weapons.

And as clarified in the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=3), a thrown melee weapon does not qualify:

> **Does the Archery fighting style work with a melee weapon that you throw?** No, the Archery feature benefits ranged weapons. A melee weapon, such as a dagger or handaxe, is still a melee weapon when you make a ranged attack with it.

So, while the thrown object is a Monk Weapon, it would still be a thrown weapon (arrows as an improvised weapon technically), unless it was a ranged weapon already such as a dart or net.